# Post order for a general tree? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

I asked this question earlier, but I did not know the difference between a rose tree and general tree. Now I know that the data structure is slightly different.

```
data GTree a = Leaf a | Branch [GTree a]
```

I would like to write a postorderG function that would give me a list with all the elements of Gtree in postorder.

I know how to do it for a binary tree.

```
data BTree a = Nil | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a) 

postOrder :: BTree a -> [a]
postOrder Nil = []
postOrder (Node x lt rt) = (postOrder lt) ++ (postOrder rt) ++ [x]
```

Comment: Is this a general Tree data Tree a = Empty | Node a [Tree a]

Comment: or this                                                                                                                     data GTree a = Leaf a | Branch [GTree a]

Answer (score 2):

A `GTree` just has as many branches as you wish, not just two. The concept for post order traversal is still the same: visit **all** branches before visiting the current node. You can do this either with explicit recursion on the list of branches or with `map` or `reduce`.

Comment: Thank you! How would I do it with explicit recursion?

Comment: preorderTree ::GTree a -> [a]
preorderTree (Leaf children) = a : concatMap preorderTree children               why is this not working?

Comment: @Gloria95 You mean aside from it not defining how it works on a `Branch` value?

Comment: For this tree there's no value to visit at the current node anyway, so the concept of preorder vs postorder is meaningless.

Comment: @amalloy Good point. Since `Branch` does not require an `a` like `Node` does, it holds no data.

Comment: @Gloria95 I suggest using `map` on the list of trees in the branch rather than trying to do it with explicit recursion.